# Return SHA256 hash of PDF page

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, hash, pdfsharp

I am writing an C# WPF application where I insert a 'header' page as the first page of a batch of PDF documents. The header page is taken from the first page of the first pdf in the batch.

The user will instigate this process, but I want to make sure that at a later date the user cannot run this process again which would result in another header being inserted.

So my plan is to get the SHA256 hash of the header page and compare it with the hashes of the first page of the other pdfs. If they match, then the first page is the same as the header page, if not we insert the header.

I knocked up the code below to test getting the hash of the first page in a pdf, but the hash is different every time it is run.

Why is it different every time?

Thanks

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;

namespace Syncada
{
    public class PDFDoc
    {

        private PdfDocument pdfDoc;

        public PDFDoc(string path)
        {
            pdfDoc = PdfReader.Open(path,PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
        }

        public string GetPageOneHash()
        {

            byte[] hash;

            PdfPage page = pdfDoc.Pages[0];
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
                doc.AddPage(page);
                doc.Save(stream,false);

                SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create();
                hash = sha256.ComputeHash(stream);
            }

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. I output the PDF to a file and compared with a hex viewer and indeed 'CreationDate' in the header and 'ID' in the trailer contained different values each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I knocked up the code below to test getting the hash of the first page in a pdf, but the hash is different every time it is run.
>
> Why is it different every time?

You do not calculate the *hash of the page* but the *hash of a new PDF document to which you add the page* in question. Unfortunately for your endeavor, PDF documents contain information like the creation date, the last modification date, and a unique ID. As these information pieces differ each time you calculate a hash, you'll never get the same hash (unless you have a collision).

Answer (score 1):

First check to see if the stream is being rewound after you save to it. If not, then you aren't actually reading anything back out, since `doc.Save(stream, false)` leaves you at the end of the stream.

To rewind a stream use `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`.

If that doesn't solve it, check to see if the document generated by `.Save` is identical across runs of your program. It is possible that there is something in the document (a timestamp, perhaps) that is different every time you generate it.

Answer (score 1):

As mkl already wrote, you are creating a new PDF document each time, so creation date/time and modification date/time will be different.

Additionally random values are used for the fonts included in the PDF, so those will also be different each time you run the program.

When using a DEBUG build of PDFsharp, the PDF file will contain many comments. You can use any DIFF program to see what's different.

Since a PDF page can reference many other objects from the PDF file, it's not an easy task to calculate a reliable hash.

A different approach: use a library like GhostScript to create an image of the first page and calculate a hash of that. If the page looks the same, you will get the same hash.

Answer (score 0):

You can also insert a custom key in the page dictionary and when you reload the file you check if the key is present.

Comment: Ah ha, now this sounds very useful! Nice tip.

Comment: The mere presence of that key does not tell you, though, whether or not the PDF has been edited. Probably the appearance of the first page has changed very much.

Comment: As I understand the header page is fixed and he does not want to insert another header if it has already been inserted. It does not say anything about editing the header and if the header content has been modified then another header could be inserted.